# angular application loading lazy load bundles when not invoked

Tags: angular, webpack

The angular application loads three 3 lazy loaded bundles even though the menu option to invoke that route pattern has not been invoked.

Verified that there is no unwanted import of this components or module that may cause this.

I am not sure how to debug this issue. Could not find any relevant resources in internet so far.

These 3 bundle load takes time and application action is waiting until that time.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was going on. In the route config, two url paths were having eager fetch, and those modules were bundled in lazy load modules. Hence those lazy loaded modules were fetched in the application eagerly.